# How to loop an array in Javascript and group by 3?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array where I need to group by 3 values within the loop.
So first I need 3 values and then loop and get the 3 next values etc.

In the code below I need to read the first 3 array values and loop through the code and then get the next 3 array values.

The data is like so: `title1,text1,image1,title2,text2,image2,title3,text3,image3`.
and is a callback from my server.

```
var myString = data;
var arr = myString.split(',');

var notisTitle = arr[0];
var notisMessage = arr[1];
var notisImage = arr[2];

// I need to loop this - first with the first 3 array values
// and the next time with the next 3 array values etc.
myApp.addNotification({
    title: notisTitle,
    message: notisMessage,
    media: '<img width="44" height="44" style="border-radius:100%;margin-top:-10px;" src="'+notisImage+'">',
    closeOnClick: true,
    onClose: function (data) {
    }
});
```

The "data" is a callback from my server (asp classic) and it gets "content" from below.

```
datan = Array (notisTitle, notisMessage, notisImage)
for i = 0 to ubound(datan)
content =  datan(0) & "," & datan(1) & "," & datan(2) & ","
next
response.write content
```

Comment: And what is `data`? Can you show an example of it?!

Comment: A `for` with `i+3` step?

Comment: Wolff, updated with how the data is looking.

Comment: Firstly, data shouldn't be a string, it should be an array of object. So if this data coming from a server you can change outputting, returns for example an array in JSON format. Now you'll get answers to your question but it just looks like a workaround to a former problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do what you need:-

```
var myString = data;
var arr = myString.substring(0, myString.length - 1).split(','); // remove last comma

for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {

  var notisTitle = arr[i];
  var notisMessage = arr[++i];
  var notisImage = arr[++i];

  //I need to loop this - first with the first 3 array values 
  //and the next time with the next 3 array values etc...         
  myApp.addNotification({
      title: notisTitle,
      message: notisMessage,
      media: '<img width="44" height="44" style="border-radius:100%;margin-top:-10px;" src="' + notisImage + '">',
      closeOnClick: true,
      onClose: function(data) {

    }
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

if `data` sets `myString` like so:-

```
var myString = 'App Notis 2,Notis text 2,http://www.manmade.se/appmanager/admin/user_images/skolappen/splash/196x196.png,App Notis 3,Notis text 3,http://www.manmade.se/appmanager/admin/user_images/skolappen/notiser/background_webb.jpg,';
```

Then you will have 7 items in the array when splitting on `,`. As you have a `,` on the end which gives index 6 `""`.

When you said:-

> Thanks BG101, but the first time it loops the "myApp.addNotification"
>   the values are empty?

I think your problem is this, but its not the first but last iteration.

remove the `,` from the end of your string and try.

**UPDATE 2**

the last comma can be removed like so:-

```
myString.substring(0, myString.length - 1).split(',');
```

see above.

Comment: Thanks BG101, but the first time it loops the "myApp.addNotification" the values are empty?

Comment: Yes I know but it does. This is how the data looks like when I output it in the browser, I don´t know if it helps?http://www.manmade.se/iphone/skolappen/notification2.asp?skickatill=Klass%204A&telefon=1234&userId=784&callback=?

Comment: Not working. I removes the 3 comma and not the last comma. I guess that I have to remove it before the split? But how?

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. But I have something wrong when I send it from my asp page. I gets empty values and I don´t understand why? What Im I doing wrong with the array in my asp page?

Comment: I just checked if the title was empty, if not loop the code. So now it works, great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad you figured it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myString = data;
var arr = myString.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i + 3) {
  var notisTitle = arr[i];
  var notisMessage = arr[i + 1];
  var notisImage = arr[i + 2];

  //I need to loop this - first with the first 3 array values 
  //and the next time with the next 3 array values etc...         
  myApp.addNotification({
    title: notisTitle,
    message: notisMessage,
    media: '<img width="44" height="44" style="border-radius:100%;margin-top:-10px;" src="' + notisImage + '">',
    closeOnClick: true,
    onClose: function(data) {

    }
  });
}
```

Consider removing assignments if you use them only once:

```
var myString = data;
var arr = myString.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i + 3)
  //I need to loop this - first with the first 3 array values 
  //and the next time with the next 3 array values etc...         
  myApp.addNotification({
    title: arr[i],
    message: arr[i + 1],
    media: '<img width="44" height="44" style="border-radius:100%;margin-top:-10px;" src="' + arr[i + 2] + '">',
    closeOnClick: true,
    onClose: function(data) {

    }
  });
```

Comment: Then the problem is in your `data` variable.

Comment: Ok, just updated with how the data variable is looking. You can see here how it looks.http://www.manmade.se/iphone/skolappen/notification2.asp?skickatill=Klass%204A&telefon=1234&userId=784&callback=?

Comment: Is it the last comma that is wrong in the data variable? But how do I remove that before the split?

Comment: `myString = myString.substring(0, myString.length - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i = i + 3) { 
  var first = arr[i];
  var second = arr[i+1];
  var third = arr[i + 2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following code might suite your requirement

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var len=arr.length;

for(var i=0;i<len;i=i+3) {
  var slicedArr = arr.slice(i,i+3);
  console.log(slicedArr);
}
```